# Modifying headset's microphone to hear from it?

Tags: audio, cables, microphone

## Problem?

I have a headset with a microphone, like this:

[This is my headset http://www.gd-wholesale.com/userimg/21/3701i2/stereo-headphone-with-microphone-q-805mv-801.jpg](http://www.gd-wholesale.com/userimg/21/3701i2/stereo-headphone-with-microphone-q-805mv-801.jpg)

## Good for you. What do you want?

I want to use my headset's microphone as a real microphone.

## It's already a real microphone, you noob.

Sorry for ignorance, let me explain. I want to say something to my microphone and I want to hear what I say from microphone, like singers and reportes do. I will use it as something like voice volume booster. I plan using a battery for energy, and headset's circles to hear from microphone. I disassembled my headphone but I don't know what shall I do know. I don't know which cable wire I must connect to which cable wire.

I'm waiting for your answers.
Thanks in advance

Comment: +1 for style, but what are you really trying to achieve? If you just want to hear yourself talk, take the headphones off. Obviously, you want to also do something else with these signals. What is it?

Comment: Hearing yourself talk is not the same audio that will be going through the wires. I know this because I am completely tone deaf and the only way I can hear it is through what the speakers are projecting. This is definitely a question about electronic design of hardware connecting the microphone directly to the speakers in the headphones and what components are needed.